# Single color produces multiple colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

Aloha,

I had a client send me a logo to use for making a sign.  When i opened it in Illustrator it had several colors in it, but when i look at the swatches there are only 2.  There are about 3 different colors that all come up as the same swatch when I click on them. First thing i check was opacity, but they are all at 100%.  When I open the color palate they all read the same CMYK as the darker blue.

I looked at the swatch and it's labeled "book color" instead of "spot Color", but i haven't encountered this before.  I need to figure out the PMS colors so i can match the paint, but they all read the same PMS.

Does anyone know how to convert these into normal CMYK values, or better yet PMS color swatches?

Comment: Are they just tints of the same color?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your issue is. Is it possible to post a screenshot of the logo (or part of it) and the swatch panel? It's normal the spot are named "book" (it's spot), not all swatches get added to the swatch panel, and not all swatches are used. Start by doing a "select unused"then delete them in your swatch panel options. To convert them to normal spot, you might need to do it manually, there's no automatic way. https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/using-creating-swatches.html

Answer (score 0):

If the logo consists of multiple elements, fully ungroup it. With the logo objects selected, open the appearance pallet (Window>Appearance). I suspect you will see more than one fill listed. If it does indeed have multiple fills, each one can have its own opacity and transparency settings that may not be apparent when the object is initially selected. You can delete unwanted fills by selecting them and clicking on the trashcan icon.